# Simple NSOutlineView Retain Crash

Tags: swift, macos, nsoutlineview

I've got a simple `NSOutlineView` setup in my OSX Swift project feeding from a basic array but its causing an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crash.

Having enabled zombies, it crashes with the following error:
`[NSMutableIndexSet retain]: message sent to deallocated instance`

Heeeelp! Here is my code:

```
class SidebarViewController: NSViewController, NSOutlineViewDataSource {

    //MARK: Vars

    @IBOutlet var sidebar : NSOutlineView?
    var data : [String] = ["Assemblies", "Parts", "Customers"]


    //MARK: Init

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
    }


    //MARK: NSOutlineView Delegate / Datasource

    func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, numberOfChildrenOfItem item: AnyObject?) -> Int
    {
        return data.count
    }

    func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, isItemExpandable item: AnyObject) -> Bool
    {
        return false
    }

    func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, child index: Int, ofItem item: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject
    {
        return data[index]
    }

    func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, byItem item: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject?
    {
        return item
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like the code causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that `objectValueForTableColumn` method require an `obj_c` object returned. So returning `String` in my array doesn't work. I changed this to `NSString` and it now works.

Comment: Please mark your answer as correct, so that others will know that this solved it for you.